# Office 365 painfully slow on Remote Desktop and Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, remote-desktop, office365

I've noticed that Office 365 (version 16.0.7167.2060) running on a remote computer is very slow when I connect from a PC running Remote Desktop (version 10.0.14393.187) and Windows 10 (Pro version 1607).

The PC I'm connecting to is running Windows 7 Enterprise SP1. Office 365 applications take 3-6 seconds to refresh. All other applications refresh in less than a second. Office 2010 applications refresh fine.

I can connect to the same computer from a Mac with Remote Desktop and performance is fine. I can connect to the same machine from a PC running Windows 7 and the performance is fine. I've used the Windows store version of Remote Desktop and I have the same problem.

I've tried connecting from a different PC with Windows 10 and Remote Desktop and I have the same problem. Has anyone else experienced this issue?

Comment: Have you tried disabling animations? Rendering these via RDP would have some type of slow down.

Comment: No, but I just did. It didn't seem to help. I tried the various options in Remote Desktop to improve performance, but none of them helped.

Comment: You tried this? `Control Panel\Ease of Access\Ease of Access Centre\Use the computer without a display\Adjust time limits and flashing visuals\Turn off all unnecessary animations`

Comment: Yes, I did. It did not make any noticeable difference. The problem seems to be specific to Office 365 because everything else performs fine.

Comment: This also applies to "regular" Office 2016 when you use RDP to a desktop and run Outlook, Word, etc. I mean slow like LITERALLY a 9600 baud modem - screen paints top to bottom when opening an email takes 4-5 seconds...and I have a 1G!! Internet connection.  Arg.

Answer (score 6):

Try changing the Display Setting in Remote Desktop Connection to a lower setting than Highest (32bit).  I changed mine to True Colour 24bit and performance improved ten fold.

Before I did that, I found Word Macros could take over 1 minute to run.  It was also quicker to type information instead of Copy/Paste from Excel.

Now, yes it works again!!!!

Comment: I'm sorry to have come late - I just figured this out today after suffering since my office upgraded to Office 2016.  Horribly slow!!!  The 24-bit was a MAJOR improvement - still seems could be better but I can work without pounding something.  I'm on Win7 client RDPing to a Win7 machine.  Skype is the next challenge! ;)

Comment: I can confirm this makes aq majory difference. Still somewhat slow, but 10 times faster with 16 bit than with 32 bit. I am using Remote Desktop on macOS 10.13.6 onto a Win7 box.